# Secure internal network with hundreds of small devices requiring web administration

Tags: tls

Does anyone know of a method, or browser, capable of accessing older network devices once the new browsers begin blocking unsecured logins and devices that do not have https capability?

Comment: Welcome to the site. While touching an interesting topic, in its current form your question is off-topic here, as this is not a discussion forum. Please narrow it down to a specific answerable question. Take a look at the [tour] and the [help] for further guidance.

Comment: I'd suggest asking something like "What options are there for maintaining access to older devices which cannot be updated?", which may be more answerable.

Comment: I changed the post, thank you. If there is another place I should be placing my original post, please let me know.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't just enable HTTPS on these devices?

Comment: Many devices do support https, but the login page is unsecured. Firefox doesn't like that currently and will eventually not allow it. Some devices allow certificates to be installed, but a cert with reasonable encryption is too large for the firmware. The https option would also mean managing a large number of DNS entries as https requires a FQDN per device.

Comment: Are telnet or SSH interfaces not available?

Comment: More and more devices we are finding, no longer support CL over SSH. Only http/Flash/CSS/HTML5. It is unfortunate.